# Use of the same Hardware with many processes

Tags: process

I have 1 HW - a phone, Which **I control over from windows** os.

This phone have both twitter and Instagram installed.
I have 2 python processes (video players) running on windows / linux, one is watching IG and the other Twitter over this phone.

What is the best practice to make sure both will **not run at the same time** ?

- I guess a power failure can be done such that a process can terminate ungracefully.
- I am currently using one main file to popen each of the "players" in a loop.
  I also uses Singleton that created a "lock" file, but under some race this file keep exist while the process died.

Answer (score 1):

Standard way to ensure mutual exclusion (or in your case ensuring that two programs are not running at the same time) is to use a [lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)). You can implement a lock in many ways, one being a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).

Instead of using a simple lock file, use a suitable synchronization primitive or implement one of the synchronization algorithms that yield such primitives.

Since you are using python, the synchronization primitives of multiprocessing are available to you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock

If that is not an option in your use case, have a look at the mutual exclusion solutions for distributed systems described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutual-exclusion-in-distributed-system/, e.g. the Suzuki–Kasami algorithm

Comment: I know lock / Semapore and how to use it in a single core / one process system. How do I implement one on an OS ? can you recommend " suitable synchronization primitive" used in windows ?